# What is the radius of curvature of a space curve? Is it the same as a plane curve?

Tags: geometry

The radius of curvature of a plane curve is defined to be the absolute value of the reciprocal of the curvature i.e. [mathematical formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgUWD.png)

So for the case of a three-dimensional curve or space curve, can the same formula be used to evaluate the radius of its curvature? If so, what is the intuition behind it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet–Serret_formulas.

Comment: Correct link: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet-Serret_formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas)